# Newly created fan page has no "Go to App" button

Tags: facebook-page

I am making changes in preparation for February 1.  I have a fan page with 30000 likes.  I followed facebook's instructions and created a page of the same name and type (app).  The new page does not have any likes (this may take a while?).  Nor does the game have the button that my other apps all have (Go to App).

I can't find where this is.  I've looked through the newly created page's settings.  I've also looked through the app's settings.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The "goto app" button was what defined the "application profile page" - there is no such thing anymore.  No (new) applications will ever be able to have that type of page again.  You'll have to just use your normal page that you created. 

 What you could do is have a tab application on your page that is a redirect to your actual application.</strike>

As the OP has shown in his comments below,  my answer above was misleading.

I re-read the article in the [blog post number *six hundred and eleven*](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/) linked to by the OP and it stated there :

> The Like migration can take up to seven days, and it may be several
>   hours before you see any movement on the Page. If you have a Vanity
>   URL associated with your App Profile Page, we will transfer the Vanity
>   URL to the Facebook Page so long as one doesn’t already exist for the
>   Page.

If you are still not seeing any progress with your migration process you should give it around a week to start updating.  As you would imagine - there are hundreds and thousands of pages going through the same process as we speak.
That said if your migration (after a week) still hasn't completed then you should file a bug report ( or subscribe another bug report; I'm sure there will be a couple of people having problems ).  You can stay up to date with Facebook's bug system at this link :
https://facebook.com/help/bugs
Another great place to "stay in the loop" is the [Developers Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap).  All changes will be listed there well before they are implemented. ( 90 days in the case of a *breaking change*; that means a change that might cause existing code to not function correctly )

Comment: very interesting.  For some reason my other app, which I was told to create a new page for, has this button on the new page.  You can check it out at https://www.facebook.com/pages/Airport-Madness-3/169548073145011

Comment: It says "For new apps, the Page has a “Go To App” button on the top right".  I've just migrated all of my app profile page likes to new pages, and they all seem to have this button now.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  I can't vote up yet due to lack of reputation, but thanks.

Comment: No problem @Roger, If you found my answer (2nd one of course ;) to be helpful - you can mark it as answered by clicking the "tick" at the top left of the answer.